# Unable to call Oracle procedure from SSRS (Recently switched to Windows 10 64-BIT)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a major problem with my SSRS now since moving over to windows 10 on a different machine. Basically when I try and query the proc in dataset properties or try and preview an existing report I get the following error.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 
[Procedure name]line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
```

My old OS was a 64bit thin client (VMware) on windows 7
I have now switched to windows 10 64bit on a laptop.

Our reporting environment is SSRS calling oracle procedures for our datasets in which we then create the reports on. I am stumped as to why this error is occurring on my new system as to my knowledge I have the same software on both and nothing has changed from a procedure point of view.
I'm using a 32bit version of an oracle client with 32bit Visual Studio, like I said its an identical setup software wise.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's a pretty specific error message. Did you already check your parameter properties, query, and the Dataset Properties > Parameters tab to make sure you are passing them in correctly?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. There is nothing wrong with the procs or parameters. My team use them all fine. They are untouched. The issue is I cant call them since moving to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with Oracle client 12c. I downgraded to 11g and all now ok.